# Discord JS, console.log undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, undefined

I want to use the `msg.content` somewhere else,

```js
const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
message.channel.send('How many players?');

const msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
  max: 1,
  time: 10000,
});
console.log(msg.content);
```

but when I console log `msg.content` it says that it's `undefined` but when I console log everything I can see the content (image below)

[image: logs]

It works when I use `.then` but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Looks like `awaitMessages` returns a collection, not a message. You will need to iterate over the collection to grab all messages, or use `collection.first()` https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) you can see that `TextChannel.awaitMessages()` returns a Promise to a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) which is not the same as an array.

So what could work is this:

```
const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
message.channel.send('How many players?');

//it will return a collection even if there's only one message in it
var msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
  max: 1,
  time: 10000,
});

//convert Collection to array (Array of all messages the filter caught)
msg = Array.from(msg.values())[0];

//that should give the content of the first message the filter caught
console.log(msg.content);
```

I hope that this works. If not please tell me.

Comment: @Vince My dumb mistake... Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks now it works, it was my first time using stackoverflow and I really appreciate your help.